# Functions: how to make them cope with multiple options?

Tags: python-3.x

I recently created a code that allows me to process html from this news website (tempo.co) and translate it into English. I created a set of functions to clean the text and make it more user-friendly while extracting the html from various parts of the website.

Q1) As the site have a bunch of categories (economic, business, politics, technology etc), I was wondering if there is a way to simplify my functions so that I don't have manually code for every single category in the news site? See code below.

Q2) For my function "site_category", if I inputed choice wrongly, how can I get the code to stop running, i.e. something akin to the in-built python function "break"?

```
def site_category (choice):

    if choice == "National":
        National = "https://nasional.tempo.co/"
        return National

    if choice == "Business":
        Business = "https://bisnis.tempo.co/"
        return Business

    else:
        print("Error, please try again.")

def doc_naming (choice, date):

    if choice == "National":
        filename = "Tempo-" + choice + " " + str(date) + ".docx"
        return filename

    if choice == "Business":
        filename = "Tempo-" + choice + " " + str(date) + ".docx"
        return filename

def remove_title_ends(choice, title):

    if choice == "National":
        new_title = title.strip("- Nasional Tempo.co")
        return new_title

    if choice == "Business":
        new_title = title.strip("- Bisnis Tempo.co")
        return new_title


def text_cleaner (text):
    truncate1 = text.find("text=") + 5
    truncate2 = text.find("pronunciation") - 2
    cleaned_text = text[truncate1:truncate2]

    return cleaned_text

choice = input("Enter 'National' for national news, 'Business' for business news: ")
category = site_category(choice)
print("You have chosen category: " + choice + "." )

date = input("Provide the date you are monitoring: ")
document_name = doc_naming(choice, date)
print("Your file name is " + document_name)
```

Comment: You can simplify your functions a bit. In `site_category ` you could return directly the url without doing `National = ...` then `return National`. In the next function, the result does not depend on the choice so go with`def doc_naming (choice, date): return "Tempo-" + choice + " " + str(date) + ".docx"`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean stop the code entirely, you can `raise` an exception:

```
def site_category (choice):

    if choice == "National":
        National = "https://nasional.tempo.co/"
        return National

    if choice == "Business":
        Business = "https://bisnis.tempo.co/"
        return Business

    else:
        raise ValueError("Error, please try again.")
```

This will exit the program with the error message unless you catch the exception in an outer scope. See [the documention](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) for more information.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. Thanks!